# Why did the mouse beat the light pen, paddle, and other pointing devices?

Tags: mouse, hardware

I recently watched [the mother of all demos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJDv-zdhzMY) from 1968 which did an excellent job of showing how computers can be personal.

Something that stood out to me was the mouse.  This device has remained pretty much the same since 1968.  [The inventors couldn't even remember who first called it a mouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1oNBImSX0M) and they said they had created about 5 different devices to help a user point at things on the screen but everyone in the lab preferred the mouse.

About 12 years ago I had the opportunity to watch an adult try and use a mouse for the first time.  It looked incredibly awkward and frustrating.

What is it about the mouse that makes it a good user experience?  If you disagree that the mouse provides a good user experience then why do people seem to prefer it over other pointing devices?

One final question, what would it take to make a computer mouse obsolete?

(I don't recall ever seeing a mouse used in Star Trek or Star Wars)

Comment: While at University we took several days to talk about why the mouse actually rated low on a scale of usability. I'm trying to locate a paper or two that actually discusses this (over my "a professor once told me" story). Another personal experience is watching adults who never used a mouse before, while teaching an intro Computer Science class -- "good UX" would not be how I would describe some of their experiences. I should have taken video! :)

Comment: Many people put their money on the light pen since it was already a familiar tool but it didn't make it very far.

Comment: What about the TRACK BALL. It has all the advantages of the top answer but takes less space and is much easier (in my experience teach folks over 60 to use the computer) to use than the mouse.

Comment: As for obsolescence - we starting to see the answer around us: touch interfaces and voice recognition (both of which are very common in Star Trek).

Comment: It hasn't beaten the finger, still our preferred "device" for "pointing".... See "Tablet Computer"

Comment: Crically, modern mice with ergonomic shape and extra buttons are biased against left handed users. From a UX viewpoint they _have got worse_.

Comment: "I don't recall ever seeing a mouse used in Star Trek" - I do: In [Star Trek IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home), Scotty, after being told to "use the mouse" to control the computer from the 1980s, picks up that little device and confidently starts speaking his commands for the machine into it... - Yet, voice control, though technically feasible, is not really used today either.

Comment: "I don't recall ever seeing a mouse used in Star Trek or Star Wars" - of course, I don't recall ever seeing someone *actually work* using the interfaces shown on those shows, rather than just actors pressing a few random button-lookalikes for a few minutes (where issues such as arm fatigue do not come into play).

Comment: To be fair, I've never seen anyone go to the bathroom on Star Trek either.

Comment: I don't recall seeing anyone in movies ever use the mouse

Comment: It is not clear to me that the mouse did beat other devices. Yet I still upvoted the question. Trackballs, direction buttons, drawing tablets and joysticks existed alongside mice.  As @JonStory said, the finger, on a touch pad and then a touch screen, has had a resurgence, despite the underlying technology being more complex and more expensive.

Comment: There is a learning curve to using a mouse, but once you've overcome it, it is very efficient. A trackpad /touchpad is the same concept, but I still prefer the mouse. When mousewheels first came out, I thought they were useless, but when I went back to a non-wheel mouse, I found myself reaching for the wheel, so that's a big improvement. I think it is incorrect to say "This device has remained pretty much the same since 1965"

Comment: Yeah, I was in high school when we got our first mouse.  Very awkward it was.  However, light pens require holding and arm up in the air which was even more awkward.  Trackballs tended to not track as well and also were more painful in extended use.  TrackPoint and trackpads weren't out for years...  :-)

Comment: @dcorking Also nubs, which our new work laptops all came with

Comment: @Gusdor that's why I bought  [logitech G300](http://support.logitech.com/en_gb/product/8551). It's symmetrical (I use the mouse left handed except for fine work like photo editing) but with configurable extra buttons (have to use windows to configure it :( ) and not too small or badly shaped.

Comment: @Izkata : Great addition! I think you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick . Until I read that WP article today, I didn't realize that these little pressure sensitive sticks are widespread.

Comment: Those pointing sticks are definitely not the norm, but can be had.  My home laptops have all been special ordered with the pointing sticks and without trackpads (I find the pointing stick to work better over long hours vs the trackpads that dry out my fingers and then stop responding after a couple hours of heavy usage).

Comment: Actually, the truth of the matter is the mouse piddled on those others and shorted them out.

Comment: @DaveAlger I tried to find the trending information for which you are looking. No joy. I'd recommend that you ask that as a separate question, and maybe link the two questions to each other. The potential replacement is probably even a third question.

Comment: I was able to find data showing the rise of mobile devices interacting with the web more than desktop computers for the first time last year which is a start but even some mobile devices could still be getting input from a mouse (though much less likely) - Thanks for looking @Dane - I entirely agree that this post should be split into multiple questions linked together but have never done that yet. (any help is welcome)

Comment: @DaveAlger Our higher rep brethren may have more magical means at their disposal, but I would just ask two new questions and put hyperlinks in the new ones to this one, and then edit this one to include links to the new ones.

Comment: "About 12 years ago I had the opportunity to watch an adult try and use a mouse for the first time. It looked incredibly awkward and frustrating." - possibly because nobody explained it to them, because everyone assumed everyone else knew it.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**Positive aspects of the mouse user experience:**

- The mouse position on the mouse pad is highly analogous to the position of the cursor on the screen. Two-dimensional movement of the mouse on its resting surface translates into two-dimensional movement of the cursor on the screen.
- The user can take hold of the mouse and can release the mouse without affecting the position of the cursor. Beginning to use the mouse does not reset the position of the cursor (unlike touch screens). Slight movements of the cursor can thus be effected by slight movements of the mouse.
- Rapid movements of the cursor can be accomplished with precision (unlike a joystick). Once a user is comfortable with the mouse, moving to a specific point in two dimensions becomes very quick. Take note of the quick and accurate input employed in first-person shooters.
- There is nothing to hold up, so the hand can be at rest when using the mouse (unlike a pen).  In addition, the cursor can be moved across the screen a great distance without needing to move one's hand very far (and the movement/acceleration rates can be configurable).
- The mouse is separate from the screen, so using it does not obscure the display apart from the pixels of the cursor, which are arguably part of the display rather than part of the input (cursors are also used when editing text on a touchscreen, for example).
- The pressure exerted to click a mouse button is perpendicular to both axes of movement which minimizes unintentional input (trackballs are even better at this, but pressing a button on something like a [Wii remote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote) is difficult to do without also causing the cursor to move).

Comment: Of course, mouse acceleration does its best to frustrate our brains' attempts to understand the correlation between the mouse position and cursor position.

Comment: @Almo: Some mouse drivers work better than others; someone who uses a decent mouse/driver can generally point to an arbitrary spot pretty quickly with only one or two motions.

Comment: The first and second bullets are true, but really are more applicable to the limitations of the screens at the time rather than the input device itself.

Comment: @Almo http://smoothmouse.com/ if you don't use it already ;)

Comment: Excellent answer, but arguably one of the most important features of the mouse is not on your list. You can move, select (via button press) and scroll/zoom (with the mouse scroll wheel) all at the same time with precision and ease and it isn't awkward at all.  This is SUPER important in games but applies in other uses also.

Comment: I have to say... I often forget that most people never disable mouse acceleration. Turning up sensitivity and disabling acceleration will allow for an incredibly higher degree of consistent experience, once you get the initial few days of adjusting.

Comment: Also, many cheap mice these days have a handy "dpi" button which will switch the tracking resolution at a click. I find it extremely useful since it allows for fine-grained precision when you need it (e.g., design or painting) and allows for higher speeds when doing typical work. I wished more expensive mice would have it too

Comment: This answer is getting long. The problem is that it's a list of things that are nice about a mouse, but doesn't necessarily explain why they are in more widespread use. There are plenty of bullet points that can be created for positive aspects of many other input devices as well.

Comment: @DA01 I was focused on this question: "What is it about the mouse that makes it a good user experience?" That strikes me as the crux of the question.

Comment: @Dane that's a fair point. It's almost as if there are two separate questions in the original post.

Comment: Is it really easier to click a track ball without sliding your finger than a mouse button without sliding the mouse? That's not my experience though I've logged way more hours using a mouse than a track ball

Comment: I used to use a joystick as mouse and found that the precision was good but the speed was awful.  This was in win95 so acceleration wasn't relevant.  It was quite comfortable as well.

Comment: @Dunk (I'm neither an UX expert nor a massive touchscreen user) You can achieve a lot of that on a touchscreen/touchpad too, with two-finger gestures, moreover, you have a separate gesture for zooming and scrolling, which you don't have with a wheel-equipped mouse. Of course you can't simultaneously move and scroll, but you need this I think really only for gaming.

Comment: I would add to your third or fourth bullet point (based on distilling a point from @Michael Zuschlag) that a mouse allows the user to use their *kinesthetic* sense instead of their vision to know where the mouse is.

Comment: @Bobson I don't think that is true. Because of mouse acceleration and also the ability to pick up the mouse and move it to another position on the mouse pad, the physical location of the mouse does not tell you where the cursor is. A puck on a tablet, however, would have this positive property: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet#Puck

Comment: @Dane - I'm not referring to where the cursor is - it's more a sense of how far you're moving the mouse without looking at it.  It's a property shared by trackpads (which you can feel your finger on), but not pens/styli (which have a tip you can't directly sense) or joysticks (which don't provide any kinesthetic feedback), and is useless on touch screens (because you're already looking at it).

Comment: @Bobson That doesn't add up for me. While I agree that the mouse has certain advantages when it comes to knowing how to move it to effect the desired computer response, every input you mention involves the human hand touching a device and engaging in physical movements. The involvement of proprioception alone doesn't strike me as an advantage.

Comment: @Dane - Fair enough.

Comment: Pens can contribute to, and worsen arthritis more than a Mouse. I can barely write anymore regardless of which pen I use, which is a shame, because I still prefer pen and paper for certain things. I'm not sure if it's actually a proven fact, but I also know of people who can use a mouse just fine, but cannot use a pen anymore without much discomfort.

Comment: Almost everything you said also applies to Touchpads.

Answer (score 54):

It was more scientific than one might think. At its inception the mouse was found to provide [better speed-accuracy than light pens or joysticks](http://students.asl.ethz.ch/upl_pdf/358-report.pdf). This is why the mouse was chosen for use in the original direct-manipulations user interfaces. The mouse’s superiority has since been [replicated](http://www.yorku.ca/mack/CHI93a.html) with other input devices, such as styli and trackballs, justifying it’s continued use today. These findings were documented at a time when the mouse was alien to most users, so the mouse’s superiority cannot be attributed to it being ubiquitous and thus very familiar. There is just something neurological and biomechanical about it that makes it better.

Direct touch is the only thing [shown to have better speed-accuracy](http://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR2007-053.pdf) than a mouse. However, direct touch has notable disadvantages:

- It requires larger targets so you cannot fit as much interactive information on a screen.
- It can mean the hand occluding the screen.
- It requires more motion to select things distributed around the screen, which can be tiring. A mouse, in contrast, has gain (I only have to move my mouse 3.5 inches to slew the 25.25" breadth the my desktop monitor, yet I can still highlight the letter "i" in this answer).
- The display position must compromise between easy viewing and easy touching. With a mouse I can keep eyes up and my hands down for greater comfort, rather than hold my hands in the air, or bend my spine down.
- You can’t incorporate physical buttons or other controls that provide flexible input and tactile feedback.
- One word: fingerprints.

Touchscreens are also more intuitive than mice, which is why we first saw them in kiosks. The non-intuitiveness of the mouse was clear to me as well from watching an adult first try a mouse in the early 1990s. As another datapoint, no one has made a successful [cat game](http://www.techhive.com/article/2039061/seven-apps-for-playful-cats.html) with a mouse interface, ironically. However, “non-intuitive” in this context means “non-familiar,“ so it’s less of an issue today since mice are so ubiquitous. A mouse is intuitive in the sense that once you learn it, it's easy and never forgotten. Touch remains a serious competitor for the mouse. However, for most uses, a mouse is better, if (a big if) you have flat stable surface to put the mouse.

Unless someone comes up with something completely new, the mouse is unlikely to be replaced for the kind of tasks it’s currently used for. What would be complete new? What could make a direct manipulation UI easier? If anyone knew that, it would be here already. Maybe something like a [glove with force-feedback](http://www.cyberglovesystems.com/products/cybergrasp/overview)?

Don’t look at science-fiction shows for the future (except for maybe [what *not* to do](http://www.zuschlogin.com/?p=56)). SciFi shows hate mice because there is too little motion (the gain again), and therefore too little drama. They want the actor to make big motions. And they like speech so there is dialog.

Comment: Here's *something new*: a touchscreen that can dynamically form physical buttons on its surface. (http://tactustechnology.com/) I suppose it's not something *completely* new as it combines old-style tactile buttons with the flexibility of a touchscreen interface. Still pretty cool tho IMO

Comment: The direct touch disadvantages can almost all be seen as advantages. It all depends on context.

Comment: @ITBear I had ideas like what you've linked for a long time now. I've never been a hardware person, so I didn't try to patent/invent such a thing, but I always figured technology would get there some day.

Comment: @DA01 - getting tired/back pain can be seen as advantage? :D

Comment: @Davor ha, no, but that's not really an issue today anymore.

Comment: Regarding SciFi and mice, I can't avoid remembering this scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hShY6xZWVGE

Comment: Nice to see an answer here that actually cites some *evidence* (unlike all the other answers). But then I'd expect nothing less from you Michael!

Comment: Your cited study doesn't really show that direct touch is more accurate than mouses - it is actually unrelated to the matter at hand (har, har). It is about using two mouses _versus_ two hands to input stuff. It's also worth to note that while your study do a small comparison on one-mouse vs one-hand, the mouse ends up better.

Comment: @Pereira; I was referring to only the result in the one-hand experiment involving a simple selection task (p650). Touch had faster selections (lower b in Fitt’s law), and that included the time to recover from errors. Thus touch had better speed-accuracy combined. The mouse was better on errors alone, and was faster at dragging. So touch _can_ beat the mouse, but not necessarily on everything. So, yeah, in general: mice rule.

Answer (score 18):

The light pen, if you think about it, is merely a stylus. And that has remained a popular method of input--just in slightly different form factors:

- light pen
- stylus on input tablets (such as wacom's products)
- stylus on pressure screens (Palm Pilots, Newtons, etc.)
- today's touch capacitance styli for most touch screens
- your finger

So, I wouldn't say the mouse 'beat' it. It's certainly the primary input method on most systems, but the concept of the light pen is still around.

As for why the original light pen didn't thrive, my guess is ergonomics and resolution. Screens back then were heavy, low-resolution CRTs and using a light pen was always awkward. It was like working on a white board all day. Not ideal for the arm, back or neck. :)

As for why the light pen is not the primary input device, well, it is--at least becoming increasingly so as we use touch screens. It's your finger. Your finger is now what the light pen was a half-century ago--a way to interact directly with the screen.

Prior to today, however, most users needed to interact with what was shown on screen--but not the screen itself. Mice were more ergonomic and cheaper for that task, hence we all have mice now.

UPDATE:

jpmc26's comment got me thinking of a way to sum it up. Perhaps one way to put it is that *direct* input (ala a stylus) has always been the preferred means to interact with elements on the screen, however it was never all that practical until said screens have become adjustable and portable. The mouse was a 'temporary' compromise until we figured out how to shrink our displays.

Comment: The stylus (and touchscreen) is a reasonable solution only for short term (<3 m) use on a vertical screen or longer term use on a horizontal screen.

Comment: Always [remember the gorilla](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/gorilla-arm.html)!

Comment: @ClayNichols agreed...hence my comment on ergonomics. It just didn't make sense on CRT monitors. On your iphone, though? Now it makes sense.

Comment: I suppose one could say the light-pen was maybe 40-50 years behind the display technology. It made sense for light-weight, hand-held displays...but not 80lb CRTs on a desk.

Comment: Essentially, what you're saying is that the stylus becomes a viable input method when you can easily adjust the position of the screen/input pad.

Comment: @jpmc26 yea, that's a good way to put it. Conversely, as hand held devices become the norm, the mouse becomes *less* practical.

Comment: "until we figured out how to shrink our displays" - while I'm aware you're referring to the special subclass of mobile devices here, in general, displays are not getting smaller, of course. Each of my workstations so far has had a larger display than the previous one, and I don't (want to) see that trend end any time soon.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper no, not referring to a particular subclass. *all* displays have gotten smaller. A 24" LCD is drastically smaller than a 19" CRT in terms of volume, weight, adjustability and portability.

Comment: @DA01: My current workplace monitor is drastically larger in terms of physical screen area than the one I had 5 years ago, and that was drastically larger in terms of physical screen area than the one I had 10 years ago, etc. Also, if something is "smaller (...) in adjustability and portability", what does that mean?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm talking overall physical size. You can hold a large tablet in your lap that 15 years ago would have been a 50lb box. Your workplace monitor today can likely tilt in all directions...possibly rotate...and some even can be placed in your lap.

Comment: @DA01: Ok. So, the special subclass of devices that you may want to put on your lap or hold in your hand. Granted, my monitor may have become less massive, though that's not really relevant once it's set in place on my desk any more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20239/discussion-between-da01-and-o-r-mapper).

Comment: Your finger is an absolutely dreadful form of input, but there probably isn't a more convenient way to provide input on a mobile device. So that's why it has sustained. My finger tips are always sore because of the "finger" input device method. Unfortunately, a stylus is just another object to lose so it isn't a viable alternative.

Comment: I've never had sore fingers from using a tablet. But to each their own. That's why we have so many options.

Comment: Finger and stylus are not the same. While holding a stylus, you can move it freely within your hand. But your finger only moves as much as your joints allow it. Try writing using your finger as a pen for too long. At least I get tired of it quickly.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez yes, of course their are differences--just as their are differences with different mice and track balls. But the essence is the same: direct interaction with the UI.

Answer (score 14):

Everything is hard when you use it the first time. It's hard to use a bicycle if you haven't tried it before, hard to ski if it's the first time, as well as find the pedals gas, break and gear in any vehicle for the first time.

Still, we use the pedals in the car, and the mouse as pointing device. Probably, and without any scientific proof, because this was the way it was first developed. Douglas Engelbart did something no one ever thought about more than 50 years ago which was truly amazing.

Second, there are no real competition of the mouse. Yes, Apple has tried and come very close on there computers with its touch pads. The same with touch controls. But neither of these come close to the accuracy you can have with a mouse. Even on Mac computers, designers and illustrators use a mouse to point to that very specific pixel you need to change. This can't be done (today) on a touch pad or touch screen (unless you zoom in to the extreme, and lose context).

Comment: Well you can move the cursor via touchpad pixel-by-pixel, but it's awfully slow.

Comment: Also, letting go of the touchpad without nudging the cursor at all is an extremely basic yet challenging task.

Comment: Great answer. Time and time again I see this website questioning somethings lack of intuitiveness and completely forgetting its long term efficiency benefits. Things don't have to be immediately obvious to be better.

Comment: I disagree that there's no real competition. Very few macbook users that I see bother with mice anymore. The multi-touch touch pad is incredibly robust. I have no problems with pixel precision when illustrating via the touch pad.

Comment: @Ruslan Is it faster with a mouse? I think I drop the mouse and use my finger directly on a touchpad if I need a specific pixel.

Comment: @l0b0 You need a better laptop.. I'm sitting here reading your comment, and totally failing to move the cursor 'accidentally' while lifting my finger in any remotely natural way.

Comment: @OllieFord in my experience, the touchpad lacks one thing: possibility to push to move. I.e. you have to position your finger somewhere, and then basically _roll_ it (or shift without friction, i.e. distort your finger shape instead of sliding) so that the movement is small enough. For mouse you can move the hand away and just slightly push. Although maybe this is not a good comparison because both methods are slow, and you can just as easily overpush.

Comment: The only tools I have found that may be better or offer more precision are VERY job-specific and expensive. For example, in 2D graphics editing I know of graphic design "tablets" that can be as simple as touchpad + pen-stylus that translates control to your monitor, to an actual touchscreen monitor + stylus (http://goo.gl/MPb0Nk - scroll down for better examples). Then, there's 3D controllers that can be pushed-pulled, tilted & twisted for navigating 3D environments one-handed (http://www.3dconnexion.com/). Invaluable if you do that work all day, but overkill for the rest of us.

Comment: @Ruslan Interestingly, that's precisely why *I* think it's easy - I roll more precisely than I push.

Comment: @Ruslan, I agree with Ollie, moving the cursor a few pixels is easier with a touchpad than with a mouse.

Answer (score 9):

Precision with minimum effort is one of the main reason why mouse is so successful. There are other reasons, of course. For instance, mouse become more influenced when personal computers were arising. It was the solution but why?

At that time, personal computers were placed in office and business environments. They were on a table and there are plenty of space for expanding units. These devices are designed in office environments.

Mouse suits with;

1. Human body elements- palm(can have four degree of freedom,shoulder,elbow,wrist,finger-click)
2. Environment, context of office. It works on a planar surface(table surface)
3. Sitting posture - main posture of office worker - Between laying down and stand-up position.
4. Less complex - technological development, carrying a (x,y) signal with a cable was easier than creating a grid.

A good design solution shall be always connected within its environmental context, the real user and his needs.

Todays computer definition is a bit different and mouse slowly integrated with another forms, especially after touchscreen boom. Currently, there is a new product for computers http://eu.swiftpoint.com/, which takes the advantage of mouse and uses the touch action movements.

[image]

Mouse types are not the same. A mouse is pointer but you may need different pointers in different environment and context. A gaming mouse can be preferred while gaming, a cad mouse will work better when designing 3d model, and a small laptop mouse will be the best choice if you have a small bag. Mouse(tools) can have other intentions in itself for creating a better experience.

I think that mouse is going to be evolve into something upcoming decade. Small form devices are going to be accepted by people because pc is no longer staying on a desktop but moves with people.

Answer (score 9):

**What is it about the mouse that makes it a good user experience?**

A mouse is very precise. It is controlled near a keyboard, which allows for quick switching from pointer control to typing, and it utilizes your wrist and arm allowing your fingers of your hand to be free for extra controls.

A mouse gives the user options that other controls don't have. You can use as far as your arm can reach to move the mouse, which allows you to have more inches per pixel than a track pad (Say a track pad is 4 inches across, either more 'resets' of picking up your finger are required compared to a mouse OR each cm needs to move the pointer more pixels making it more difficult to be precise.) Your free fingers also give you access to more buttons than any other device except a joystick, which has issues with precise movements since the cursor doesn't stop until you reset the stick back to neutral.

While a track pad does allow for multi-finger controls, such as two finger drag to scroll the screen, or squeeze/widen to zoom out/in, the mouse can do these as well through the scroll wheel (sometimes requiring a modifier button to be held).

A stylus, such as your finger, is great in that you don't need a flat surface and it is always near you. Further it is easy to learn since it tends to be intuitive at the basic level. However it falls apart as you desire to do more complicated controls. Say you want to hover the mouse over an image to see it's title, for a mouse you just move the pointer, but for a touch screen you need to somehow indicate that you are moving the pointer but NOT clicking or dragging anything. Not being able to easily separate moving the cursor and clicking the cursor makes precision with a stylus to be worse than with a mouse. Some websites/browsers get around this by creating a zoomed in sub window when you click a link near other links so you can make a good selection but it is still an extra step not needed by mice. Further, the stylus method has the built in issue of you obscuring what you are clicking. You typically are looking at what you want to click on, but the act of clicking on it obscures your vision of what you are doing!

Finally there is the trackball, which I find is closest to 'replacing' the mouse. The main difference is that it suffers similar to the track pad in distance per pixel. Depending on the size of the ball, you can only move your thumb so far before you need to pick it up to get more room. At that point you either stop the ball rolling (so movement is choppy) or 'push' it which gives different results depending on the friction of the ball (variable even between the same device on different days depending on how clean your finger is.)

**One final question, what would it take to make a computer mouse obsolete?**

The only thing that will make a computer mouse 'obsolete' would be direct brain to computer interfaces that are portable and universal.

Until then, stylus's will always have the issue of obscuring what you are looking at. Trackpads will always have a smaller size to screen size ratio than possible arm length to screen size ratio. Joy sticks will always require returning to 'neutral'.

However, if you are performing actions that can be done with only the mouse movement, scroll wheel and left click (browsing the web) on a device that is small enough to be portable then the stylus is perfect and is better than the mouse. You no longer require a flat surface, the complex actions are not being used, 'obscuring' your vision typically only happens when you are changing screens anyway, you always have a stylus with you etc.

If you are performing more complex actions and require frequent typing, or if the screen is not portable or close enough to touch (connected to a projector possibly) but you also don't have a large flat surface for the mouse then a track ball might be best. If you don't want to carry a track ball or learn to get used to them, most laptops have built in track pads that would be the best option.

Currently, there are many ways to control a cursor on a screen. Every one of them has their own advantages or disadvantages in certain circumstances. Even with direct brain to computer interfaces, I could definitely see people not wanting to hook their brain up to a public computer and risk getting a brain virus or something. In which case any current device would be superior since they don't include getting your brain corrupted.

Comment: It's probably too late for me to worry about protecting my brain from corruption.  --  :)

Comment: Actually, using a stylus doesn't have to obscure your view of the screen more than marginally, and it certainly doesn't need to obscure the area of the screen you are manipulating. My experience in this regard with several Palm models was pretty good, for example. Of course, the Palm, its OS, user interface guidelines and its standard stylus were all designed from the ground up to facilitate using the stylus.

Comment: I've never used the palm so I can't comment on that. Obscuring the screen is my biggest complaint about trying to select a reddit link on my wife's surface or my phone, or manipulating the 'right click' context menu in GIMP on her surface. Since I'm not that acclimated to GIMP, every time I would 'right click' I would need to move my hand away to see what options were available, then back to select one.

Answer (score 8):

My use of a pointing tool is almost entirely for manipulating GUI objects while using a device for reading and writing, rather than for gaming or drawing. I have tried all the common pointing tools, and for me, as well as for several other people I know, none are as good as the mouse.

My guess as to why is that one's arms and hands are extensively wired with neurons for sensing and reporting their position, and we have been practicing since birth to use this feedback to move and position our hands with precision, and without having to look.

Trackballs and joysticks do not make use of that feedback, and the 'pencil eraser' (trackpoint) that IBM put on its laptops translates force to velocity, which is not an analog of any action we perform frequently in real life.

Touchscreens do use that feedback, but they have other difficulties for me:

1. The gestures have to be overloaded to capture clicks, and I keep triggering inadvertent responses.
2. Your hand obscures the very thing you are working on (a hint to designers: touch menus and the like should go up.)
3. I find it easier to make precision movements on a firm horizontal surface than on a near-vertical screen at reading height and distance. This does not, of course, apply when using a tablet.

Styli avoid point 2, and for purely pointing on a tablet, I find them very easy to use. Furthermore, they are, by far, the best for drawing, though I would like them to have the same friction feel as a pen or pencil. They also are, like mice, physical objects, and I think I am more in tune with manipulating physical objects than abstractions.

I have used touchpads up to the size of those for Macs, but they are all too small to map a position on the pad to a position on the screen and so don't take advantage of one's sense of hand position; in fact, they work like trackballs. Touchpads with buttons avoid the gesture-overload problem, but unlike mice, those buttons are not at your fingertips.

Answer (score 4):

Because mice are subtle. It was the easiest transition in a world of keyboard-only computers.

You can poke the occasional key with one hand while using the mouse with the other hand. You don't have to sit closer to the screen. The mouse just sits there innocently to the side of the keyboard.

You can also be essentially asleep and operate a mouse. The interaction isn't nearly as physical as a light pen or even a keyboard.

I recently broke my forearm very badly and hurt my wrist, and it was still pretty easy for me to do my job (developer) by turning the sensitivity all the way up and using just my fingertips.

Answer (score 2):

Although most of the other answers probably have some degree of truth to them,I don't think anybody mentioned that it may have to do with the **mapping of the movements** of a mouse to the movements of the pointer arrow.

With a mouse, you have span a whole 24 inches screen of space with just a small, 4x4 inches mousepad. This greatly saves effort on the part of the user.

With pens this is more difficult and, in a touch screen, you would have to move your hands and arms 1 meter if you want to access a point in the screen that's 1 meter apart form you. This doesn't scale well at all.

Answer (score 2):

Something no-one else has mentioned is the fact that mice are cheap and simple. Money is always a major driver.

The question is not "why is the mouse better", it's "why did the mouse beat its various competitors".

Add "cheap and simple" to the functional merits already thoroughly examined and you have an unbeatable combination.

Comment: Is that the reason it is popular though? Were mice especially cheap to make back when they were first invented? Just because they are cheap now that doesn't mean that has always been the case.

Comment: Compared to the other options, yes. It's easier to get a crude mouse to work fairly well than to get a crude light pen to work well.

Answer (score 2):

I would say three things:

1. Price - mouse was relatively simple to put together, connect it to a computer and after that it was very easy to mass produce. It was, after all, mostly mechanical design.
2. Ease of use and precision. First time users required very little tutoring, as the using it was very intuitive. Non-OS functionality offered high precision and speed.
3. Introduction of mouse to GUI eliminated need to remember any keyboard commands. You still had the advantage if using keyboard, but you didn't have to.

As there were (and are, obviously) better solutions than mouse (I'm partial to trackballs, however not for FPPs), it still won. Not always best solution wins, more often than not price is most important. Back then computers were expensive and anything that helped sell them to Average Joe was worth weight in gold.

As for the last question.

My personal bet is voice interface. Nothing else cuts down on time and cost. However that basically requires, for best performance and experience, an AI. No voice recognition software comes even close to desired functionality (which is adapting to user, not other way around).

Comment: You make several unsubstantiated assumptions here. 1) Price- *Were* they cheap to put together? Were they in fact *sold* cheaply even if they were cheap? 2) Ease of use- as OP says in his question he has witnessed people struggling with a mouse, so what makes you say that first-time users need little tutoring? Moving a bar-of-soap sized block of plastic that is tethered to a PC in order to move a tiny arrow on the screen isn't that instinctive. And thirdly- I disagree that voice interface will replace mouse. An office of people talking to their PC? And how would you use voice to draw pictures?

Comment: Price: yes, they were cheap. Again: very simple, MECHANICAL design. I'm not saying they were priced at $5/pc, but compared to other input methods it was most cost effective/ergonomic. Only design - basically - operated 100% one hand (yes, I know of joysticks, paddles etc., but early versions often required both hands.
2. Ease of use: stand by mine experience. I also have seen awkward users, but after PROPER INSTRUCTION on PROPER USE they got it.
3. "Bar of soap block of plastic" was not mouse - it was used to read position of cursor. Basically reversed utility compared to mouse

Comment: Mice might have been cheap to build, but they weren't shipped stand-alone. Early versions of the mouse came bundled with whole PCs. And those machines were expensive. So you had to spend a lot of money to be able to use one.

Comment: Mouse, and basically all pointing devices were at first very specialized hardware, as were PCs.. Remember, history of pc picks up tempo not in 1968 but much later. That's why I mentioned 3. - it went along with GUI OS like lumber mill and fire.
Sort of agree on drawing with voice being "awkward". here would be, I envision, a mix of touch and voice. But again: that's why mention of AI. Using voice in office is not difficult (all around me people use Voice Reco Software and it works), especially with modern tech (noise cancel, directional mike etc.)

Comment: Well, mouse WITHOUT PC is kinda... weird? Of course they came bundled... Imagine, however, price tag with anything else at the same time offering same or better ergonomy.
And IBM PCs and Apple II came WITHOUT mouse... IIRC. So again: mouse's popularity came late, late...

Comment: My uncle had ZX Spectrum issued to him by his company. It was 1987. No mouse. Just keyboard. I remember we played a game on it (man turning werewolf, in a maze with traps) and we had to use keyboard. No mouse. Not because expensive. Not needed really.

Answer (score -1):

I somehow do not like the learning that a user has to do before using the mouse. Understanding the movement and the impact on the screen.

For me best pointing device would be my fingers. The movement comes naturally, and there is not learning curve for it.

In 1968, computers were not as natural as they are today. I believe its high time, touch screen should become the primary pointing device.

Comment: Can you really see people in a offices with their right arm outstretched touching and sweeping their fingers over the screen *all day*? That would just be exhausting and incredibly impractical. Not to mention the fact that by doing that it means your arm is blocking loads of stuff on screen so you can't see everything, unlike a mouse cursor which only blocks out a few pixels.

Comment: Agreed with the perspective. But, I would still wanna give it a try. Prior to creation of mouse, people didn't expect something like mouse to be part of the personal computer. I understand that a lot of information may be hidden by the hands. But the interface would evolve. They always have.